# Validate Form Inputs on a good and reliable way

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

On my page im working on, are a lot of input-forms.

I want to check the user inputs before submit.

Example

**HTML/PHP**

```
<input type="text" name="adress" id="adress">
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
```

and actually im doing the following in Javascript

**Javascript**

```
function dataValidation() {
error=false;
var adress = document.getElementById('adress').value;
var amount = document.getElementById('adress').value;
if (adress == ""){
error=true;
}
if (amount >0 && amount < 999){
}
else {
error=true;
}
if (error == false){
document.forms["myForm"].submit();
}
}
```

So, basically this works fine for my, but the problem is, i have to create that function for every form, and add a IF for every field

So, im looking for a better solution

Idea 1 : Add a list, wich provides the types of input, like

```
adress = not empty,
amount = >0 && <999,
```

and then create a function, which checks all fields with that list

Idea 2: Add a tag or something directly to the input field, what it should contain. and then create a function which checks all the fields

Does somebody have a Idea how this can be done, and would like to help/advise me?

Comment: For `address` , you can do something like this `<input type="text" name="adress" id="adress" required>`.

Comment: There are dozens or hundreds of javascript validation frameworks. Google for `javascript validation framework`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this by jquery as:
your html:

```
<input type="text" name="adress" id="adress">
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
    <input type="button" id="check_input">
```

and apply jquery for all input field

```
 $("#check_input").click(function() {
       $("input").each(function() {
          var element = $(this);
       if(element.val() == "") {
          element.css("border","1px solid red");
          element.attr("placeholder","Field is empty"); 
          return false;
          }

          });
          });
```

Comment: i accept this answer becaus it worked perfectly. But i found a data-valdiation tool that is based on jQuery its called "Parsely"

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple forms with same fields try to call validation externally it will reduce some of your work apart from that i dont know any other method so lets wait for others reply

Comment: This is not much of an answer — it would be better as a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna consider using HTML5.

HTML5 can save time writing JS validations. For example to validate an email address you could use the following:

```
<input type="email" name="email" required />
```

Notice the type="email" and required. Instead of using js for validating, you could use HTML5 form attributes with Regular Expression Patterns.

For example If I want to create an input field which accepts only one numbers and 3 uppercase letters, I can easily do with it using a RegEx pattern:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9][A-Z]{3}">
```

Read a little bit more on HTML5 and RegEx. It could help you.

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't have a html-5 browser?

Comment: It wouldn't support. You can use this script to enable HTML5 API on old IE Browsers: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv

Comment: I think a better way to look at this is by using HTML5 and Sever-side validations (which you have to use either way to ensure security). All the modern browser supports HTML5, so your validation works. If a user uses a browser which doesn't support HTML5, server-side validation will throw an error.